# How to Cleanup .Designer files using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-5.x

Code Cleanup option isn't available in .Designer files. Is there any option to enable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the *.Designer.cs and/or *Designer.vb option from the **Generated file masks** area in **ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Generated Code**.

Be careful with cleaning them up, though, as in some cases doing so might render the code uncompilable.

Comment: I have removed this before discussing the question, but still Cleanup Code isn't available!

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. In my installation (R# 6.0 EAP) removing *.Designer.cs leads to ReSharper running code inspections over .designer.cs files and enabling Code Cleanup. Which R# version do you use?

Comment: Oh my version is 5.x! Thanks a lot gorohoroh ;)

Comment: You're welcome. 5.x should actually work the same way in this regard. If it doesn't, that's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need this, you are often examining code withing .designer files? I believe the main reason is the fact that these file are regenerated every time you make change and save the control, page etc.